# Can Tomcat support multiple JDBC connection pools?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat-jdbc

I have a Spring Boot application which connects to different *MySQL* databases. I am planning to add connection pool support to this application. Does the Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool (default Spring boot pool) support more than one pool for each of my databases?

Comment: Do you want the Tomcat or the Spring to handle connection pooling?

Comment: Spring. I think this will be the easiest. Basically my app is a web application written using Spring boot.

Comment: Tomcat connection pools are exposed as JNDI resources. You can add as many connection pools to the Tomcat configuration as you want since each pool will need to have a unique name for it to be added to the JNDI registry. You can also use a standalone pooling library like HikariCP that you can configure using the Spring Boot configuration.

Comment: Did this using different pooling library [C3p0](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/). I don't want to handle this in server level.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this would be different under Spring Boot, but for standard web apps you can configure this at the webapp level, by adding in `web.xml` any number of the following:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/yourname</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and in `context.xml` the corresponding number of the following:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/yourname" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxActive="30"
           maxIdle="30"
           maxWait="2000"
           removeAbandoned="true"
           ...
```